# How to parse xml to string from docx file

Tags: php

How to read `xml` from `.docx` file, my code success but only showing string not xml with `var_dump`

I need xml code to string. can you help best solution in my case ? thanks

I have a code :

```
$content = '';

$zip = zip_open('file.docx');

if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

    $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry,zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
}

zip_close($zip);

var_dump($content); // string(3270) " HelloMyName Marshall"
```

Comment: add `header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");` to the very top of the php script, right after `<?php` , so it looks like `<?php header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");` , what do you get then?

Comment: @hanshenrik thanks you, this work with header `header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
$content = '';

$zip = zip_open('file.docx');

if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

    $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry,zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
}

zip_close($zip);

var_dump($content);
```

and get string

```
string(2774) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid wp14"><w:body><w:p w14:paraId="15EEF3C5" w14:textId="3A24968F" w:rsidR="003B2D60" w:rsidRDefault="007C068C"><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">Nama </w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r><w:t>saya</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> marshall</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p><w:sectPr w:rsidR="003B2D60"><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>"
```